# Jeson parse error: Unexpected Eof

Tags: javascript, php, react-native

I am new in react native. I am facing `jeson perse error: unexpected eof`. I only trying to make a registration form. Firstly I open a new project and edit it, then run into emulator then get this error. Is it necessary to add anything to send data in the server.

Please help me

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
 AppRegistry,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,Button,TextInput
} from 'react-native';



export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
   super(props)
  this.state={
   username:'',
   useremail:'', userpassword:'',userpasswordagain:''
  }
  
  }

userRegister= () =>{
 //alert('ok');
 const{username}=this.state;
 const{useremail}=this.state;
 const{userpassword}=this.state;
 const{userpasswordagain}=this.state;
//http://localhost/reactnative/registration2.php
//https://akhterruby91.000webhostapp.com/registration2.php
fetch('https://akhterruby91.000webhostapp.com/registration2.php',{

 method: 'POST',
 headers: new Headers({
  'Accept':'application/jason',
  'Content-Type': 'application/jason'
 }),
 body: JSON.stringify({
  username: username,
  useremail: useremail,
  userpassword: userpassword,
  userpasswordagain: userpasswordagain,
 })
}).then((response) => response.json())

      .then((responseJson) => {
 
// Showing response message coming from server after inserting records.
        Alert.alert(responseJson);
 
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
 
}




  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

<TextInput
placeholder="Enter Name"
onChangeText={username => this.setState({username})}
style={{width: 200, margin: 10}}

/>

<TextInput
placeholder="Email"
onChangeText={useremail => this.setState({useremail})}
style={{width: 200, margin: 10}}

/>

<TextInput
placeholder="Password"
onChangeText={userpassword => this.setState({userpassword})}
style={{width: 200, margin: 10}}

/>

<TextInput
placeholder="Password Again"
onChangeText={userpasswordagain => this.setState({userpasswordagain})}
style={{width: 200, margin: 10}}

/>

<Button title="singup" onPress={this.userRegister} color="green"/>


<Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To login please click.
 </Text>

  </View>
  
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

here is my registration form code:

```js
<?php
 
// Importing DBConfig.php file.
include 'connection.php';
 
// Creating connection.
 $con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password,$mysql_db);
 
 // Getting the received JSON into $json variable.
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 
 // decoding the received JSON and store into $obj variable.
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);
 
 // Populate User name from JSON $obj array and store into $name.
$name = $obj['username'];
 
// Populate User email from JSON $obj array and store into $email.
$email = $obj['useremail'];
 
// Populate Password from JSON $obj array and store into $password.
$password = $obj['userpassword'];
 $passwordagain = $obj['userpasswordagain'];
//Checking Email is already exist or not using SQL query.
$CheckSQL = "SELECT * FROM registration_info WHERE email='$email'";
 
// Executing SQL Query.
$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$CheckSQL));
 
 
if(isset($check)){
 
 $EmailExistMSG = 'Email Already Exist, Please Try Again !!!';
 
 // Converting the message into JSON format.
$EmailExistJson = json_encode($EmailExistMSG);
 
// Echo the message.
 echo $EmailExistJson ; 
 
 }
 else{
 
 // Creating SQL query and insert the record into MySQL database table.
$Sql_Query = "INSERT into registration_info  values ('',$name','$email','$password')";
 
 
 if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){
 
 // If the record inserted successfully then show the message.
$MSG = 'User Registered Successfully' ;
 
// Converting the message into JSON format.
$json = json_encode($MSG);
 
// Echo the message.
 echo $json ;
 
 }
 else{
 
 echo 'Try Again';
 
 }
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is the problem:
 [Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GTej.png)

Please help me and thanks.

Comment: Sounds like your backend you are calling is not returning JSON.

Comment: i have also added the registration backend code . thank you